# jQuery Get Attribute Values in Array

Tags: jquery

I'm missing something simple here, I need to collect all the `data-event` attrs in a string array, is there a wrapper issue for elements or something I need to be aware of? this is not working:

```js
var dataEvents = $('li').map(function(el) {
     return $(el).attr('data-event');
});

console.log('DataEvents: ' + dataEvents[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li data-event="abc">TEST 1</li>
<li data-event="def">TEST 2</li>
<li data-event="ghi">TEST 3</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this use [`jQuery.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)

```js
var dataEvents = $.map($("li"), function(el) {
     return $(el).attr('data-event');
});

console.log(dataEvents);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li data-event="abc">TEST 1</li>
<li data-event="def">TEST 2</li>
<li data-event="ghi">TEST 3</li>
```

Comment: Your difference is you used $.map whereas I used array.map(..).